# How do I test multiple browsers in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber-junit

We are using Selenium WebDriver and Cucumber for our Acceptance testing.  We have a collection of Features that we want to test, each with multiple scenarios, here is an example:

```
  Scenario Outline: Unsuccessful login with W3ID credentials
    Given I navigate to the Bluecost Spreadsheet Upload Web url and receive a login screen 
    When I login using invalid credentials: "<user_id>" and "<user_pwd>"
    Then the W3ID will reject my credentials, produce an error message and I will not proceed to BCSUW

    Examples: 
      | user_id   | user_pwd |
      | baduserid | badpass  |
```

I want to test each one of these Scenarios with each browser that we need to support:  FireFox, Edge, and Chrome.  How do I run those Features and Scenarios for each one of those 3 browsers?

Comment: Do I have to write each scenario with a 'browser_type' variable that I supply on each scenario instance?  Or is there another way?

Comment: You should be able to pass 'browser_type' as a variable to the method that instantiates your driver and run the same scenario. if (browser_type.equals("firefox")) { //make instantiate driver for firefox} and similarly other browsers.

Comment: Yes, so it means that I have to repeat the same scenario for each browser type in the "Examples" section.  Was hoping there was another way.

Comment: For Selenium Webdriver you do not have to have Feature file however for the BDD like cucumber you can look at similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43446922/cross-browser-testing-in-cucumber

Answer (score 1):

I've read the post link above and one of the answers suits me:  I'm going to execute all the Features/Scenarios for every browser under test.   This may mean running the test 3 times through:  Firefox, Chrome and Edge.

Thanks for the link PJAutomator